# Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference in c# on creating Obect of different class

Tags: c#, object

I am new to c# (had c++ background before).

I have class "MyClass" which creates an object of another class "Symbols" in the same namespace. I create the object of class "Symbols" in order to define the function "add_symbol()" which is called from "MyClass".

In c++ it was quiet easy:

```
void NameOfTheClass::NameOfTheFunction()
{
}
```

But i don't know how to do in c#.
I tried the code below and got the following error(see at last).

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace shekhar_final
{

    public class Symbols 
    {
        public void add_symbol(byte processingValue) //called from MyClass
        {
            Console.WriteLine(processingValue);
        }
     }  

    public class MyClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Symbols ObjSym =new ObjSym(); //Here is the error
            using (var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0])))
            {
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length)
                {
                    byte processingValue = stream.ReadByte();
                    ObjSym.add_symbol(processingValue); //This function is called which is defined in Symbol class
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The error is (I have pointed the line causing this error in my code) :

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name `ObjSym' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

**Please help me in removing this error and any extra guidance is also appreciated because i an new to c#, Thanks**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

`Symbols ObjSym = new ObjSym();`

you should initialize with the class:

`Symbols ObjSym = new Symbols();`.

Right now you are trying to initialize your variable and not the class.

Comment: Yes it worked. But could you please give me some more guidance. Can't we do like in c++, LIke this :void NameOfTheClass::NameOfTheFunction()
{
} ?